# Disabling specific dates in jquery datepicker not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, calendar

I've got a calendar where I need to disable specific dates.

I used the code on spiceforms.com/blog/how-to-disable-dates-in-jquery-datepicker-a-short-guide/ as an example to write mine and it worked fine but at some point It stopped working and I can't find the cause, 
My code is:

```
function Disableentries(date) {
    // here I get an array of dates in yyyy-mm-dd format
    var datesarray = datesfromcalendar();

    var arraynoentry = datesarray[0];
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var y = date.getFullYear();
    var currentdate = y + '-' + (m + 1) + '-' + d ;

    // We will now check if the date belongs to disabled dates array
    for (var i = 0; i < arraynoentry.length; i++) {
        // Now check if the current date is in disabled dates array.
        if (jQuery.inArray(currentdate, arraynoentry) != -1 ) {
            return [0];
        }else{
            return [1];
        }
    }
}

jQuery(function() {
    jQuery( "#edit-available-from-datepicker-popup-0-bloque" ).datepicker({
        minDate: 0,
        beforeShowDay: Disableentries,
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    });
});
```

As a result of this code  i get some dates disabled, but they're not the ones in the array. I get disabled  the whole calendar from 2016-10-29 to 2016-12-31 and then nothing when My disabled dates are the ones shown in the pictures below:
[calendar 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tlpA.png)
[calendar 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PaL2I.png)

¿Is there anything wrong in the code or other way to solve this problem?

> Edit: the function datesfromcalendar() gets the dates that need to be
>   desabled from the calendars that appear in the pictures. Here's the
>   code:

```
function datesfromcalendar(){
  var arraynoentry= ['2000-01-15'];
  var arraynoexit= ['2000-01-16'];
  jQuery('.cal-month').each(function(){
    var month = jQuery(this).data("cal-month");
    var year = jQuery(this).data("cal-year");
    //alert(month);
    var noentry = jQuery(this).find('.cal-na-pm');
    var noexit = jQuery(this).find('.cal-na-am');
    jQuery.each(noentry,function(){
      var day = jQuery(this).text();
      arraynoentry.push(year + "-" + month + "-" + dia);
      //block entries
      //alert('hello');
    })
    jQuery.each(nosalida,function(){
      var day = jQuery(this).text();
      arraynoexit.push(year + "-" + month + "-" + dia);
      //block exits
      //alert('bye');
    })
  })
  var results = [arraynoentry,arraynoexit];
  return results;
}
```

Comment: Show us your function `datesfromcalendar()` too

Comment: the function datesfromcalendar works fine and returns the disabled dates that i get from the calendars in the picture ( I checked it first), but I'll put it here anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem.

When we sum 1 to the month (to convert months from 0 to 11 to months from 1 to 12) the result is an integer (1,2,3 ... 10,11,12). The dates on the array have the months in 01,02,03,(...) format so when we compare, only the 2 digit months return the correct results.

To solve this we have to change the month format to match the one in the array so we can compare them. 
This code does the trick:

```
var currentdate = y + '-' + ('0'+(m + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' + d ;
```